# Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, mysql

> `Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\web\xampp\htdocs\www\core\functions\users.php on line 12`

```
function user_data($user_id)
{
    $data          = array();
    $user_id       = (int) $user_id;
    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    if ($func_num_args > 1) {
        unset($func_get_args[0]);
        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';

        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id"));

        print_r($data);
        die();
        return $data;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Так делать не совсем правильно. Так как в таком случае вы не можете верно обработать ошибки в запросе, видимо, которые у вас присутствуют.

Вам стоит занести результат `[mysql_query][1]` в переменную. Затем проверяете значение, если `FALSE` - выводите ошибку (например, через [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-error.php)). Если не `FALSE` - продолжаете выполнение приложения, как задумывали.

А еще стоило бы задуматься над тем, что есть [поиск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search/?q=expects+parameter+1+to+be+resource&t=question).

**UPD**

Попробуйте вывести сам запрос и выполнить его в SQL менеджере. У вас могут быть, например, лишние или отсутствующие поля.

Воспользуйтесь этим кодом:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Проверьте, чтобы таблица `users` содержала поля: `user_id`, `user_name`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name`... etc

> Well, I've kind of made an epic
>   mistake. The mistake was that the
>   database field was called userS_id,﻿
>   while I called it user_id within php.
>   Now due to my lack of SQL knowledge I
>   'thought' stuff seemed to be working
>   when I used single quotes for the
>   field names, while I was actually
>   calling the fields data. That 'fix'
>   became a problem later in the
>   tutorials. :D

Answer (score 0):

В ошибке же написано "Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given" - "Ожидался resouce, пришел boolean", значит mysql_query вернул boolean. Значит в запросе ошибка. Перепишите строки:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id");
if(!$query) return false;
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

Comment: этот вариант заработал, но не отображает список в массиве из базы данных как это на видео http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yX1EushqcIw&feature=relmfu  3 минута 20 секунда!

Comment: здесь вторая строка лишь обрабатывает ошибку, вернувшуюся из функции mysql_query. У вас наверняка ошибка или в подключении к базе данных, или в запросе.

Answer (score -1):

Данная ошибка возникает тогда, когда запрос к базе данных, переданные в параметре функции `mysql_fetch_assoc` вернул неудачу( FALSE ), вместо набора записей из БД или успеха( при модификации набора данных, например ), TRUE. Сам запрос выглядит немножко подозрительно. Это, наверное, потому, что я не знаю структуры вашей таблицы. А этот блок кода вообще ужасен:

```
  unset($func_get_args[0]);
  $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`'; // здесь вы, не окажется запятых между полями...скорее, потому и ошибка. И вообще, возьмите к примеру, первое поле массива. Оно будет такого вида в миссиве **'`field'**, потому что это **'`, `'** не всегда будет верно...

  $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id"));
```

---

Одно только:

```
  $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
```

Сколько печали мне принесло...

---

**Попробуйте заменить на это:**

```
unset($func_get_args[0]);
$fields = implode(',', $func_get_args); // бьем поля по запятым, вместо вашего ужаса.
$fields = mysql_real_escape_string($func_get_args[0]); // подготавливаем к запросу.

$data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id")); // запросим
```

---

А вообще лучше не создавать себе геморроя с этими полями, ведь можно выделить все поля, это будет работать практически также быстро, как и ваш **implode()**...

Comment: во первых это не мой ужас, а из видео урока, во вторых ваш пример тоже не работает, та же самая ошибка(

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, ну ошибка в запросе может, кто знает =) Пишите свой код, а не занимайтесь копипастом, чтобы не возникало подобных проблем, чтож сказать...

Comment: до этого ошибок не возникало, к тому же кто не начинал из копирования, сначало учатся а потом пишут, наоборот никак не получится, к тому же ошибка не у меня одного на комментариях к видео у могих людей то же самое, не могут же все ошибится